# tex4ebook put auxilary files in directory

Tags: tex4ebook

I am using `tex4ebook` to convert a .tex project into an `.epub`

I use a command like the following:

```
tex4ebook -d output -f epub3+latexmk_build -x book
```

My problem is that the leaves my directory littered with a host of temporary and auxiliary files. This is obnoxious, and I'd like to have all of those files stored in some sort of build directory. When producing a PDF, I do this using `latexmk`'s `-output-directory` option but the similar option for `tex4ebook` only changes the location of the final epub not all the auxilary files.

Is there way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the development version of `make4ht` and `tex4ebook`, I've added a new option, `--build-dir`, which does exactly this, it puts auxiliary files to a temp directory. It will work like this:

```
$ tex4ebook -B build -d out filename.tex
```

With the version from CTAN, you can clean the aux files using this command:

```
$ make4ht -m clean book
```

This will call `make4ht` in the clean mode and it will remove all generated files for `book.tex`. It doesn't remove files in the output directory, and it seems that it also doesn't remove the Epub file and one special metadata file, `content.opf`.